# How to code webm header to open in Firefox?

Tags: c++, header, webm

I use this code to create an mkv file with a webm video:
[Code](http://www.webmproject.org/docs/vp8-sdk/example__simple__encoder.html)

The video that is generated can be opened in vlc and mplayer, however, firefox sais: *video can't be played because the file is corrupt*

How do I have to change the header so I can open it in firefox, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution... this code actually outputs a so called ivf format, while the real mkv output code can be found [here](http://www.webmproject.org/tools/vp8-sdk/example__vpxenc.html):

(Much more complicated, though)